# BigDecimal scale and trailing Zeros in MySQL/Spring environment

Tags: mysql, json, spring, hibernate, jackson

I have a Spring/Hibernate/MySQL setup where I need to store BigDecimals on the database. The values of the BigDecimals can range from 0 to 16 decimal places. I.e. all of the following are valid values:

```
12
543.34
98765.345678
0.000003344332
```

etc. So in my hibernate mappings I did this:

```
@Column(precision = 32, scale = 16)
```

Which has allowed me to store my BigDecimals and use math calculations with `MathContext.DECIMAL64`.

However when I look in the MySQL database I see values like this:

```
12.0000000000000000
543.3400000000000000
98765.3456780000000000
0.0000033443320000
```

And when I retrieve them the BigDecimals all have a scale of 16 and are filled out with trailing zeros when I serialise them out to JSON using Spring's Jackson Object Mapper.

What I would like is to get the values back from the database at the correct scale. ie.

```
12              -> scale 0
543.34          -> scale 2
98765.345678    -> scale 6
0.000003344332  -> scale 12
```

etc. Any ideas how this can be done?

Comment: You mean without regexing out the trailing 0's? Tricky proposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have managed to work around the issue by correcting the scale when the data is read back into Java. There is no MySQL fix for the handling of scaled values.